# Which CSS class is affecting the properties of a div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a complicated table (mat-table) set up where one of the columns is inheriting its width from somewhere. Without going through the hundreds of child divs to find where the width is being set is there any way I can find this out with Devtools?

Below is an example:

[image]

you can see that class-1 doesn't have a height set, but is getting it from class-n.
HTML:

```
<div class="class-1">
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-3">
      <div class="class-n"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class-1{
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}

.class-2{
  width: 50px;
}

.class-3{
  width: 100px;
}

.class-n{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/niyexayeso/edit?html,css,output

The height is being set by the lowest div 'class-n', but all the divs above are inheriting this height value. I use 'n' to denote that there could be *n* number of divs and any one of them could be affecting the parent's properties.

How can I find which div is the problem without going through them all manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out your code and the output. It seems to me like the parent element .class-1 doesn't have a initial height set on it. so it is using an auxiliary height of max-content that is why the height of class-n is affecting the height

that being set I need to look at the table to say if it is possible to find the problem without going through all the elements of the table can you take a screenshot of the table and host the image somewhere and provide the link

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't what I'm looking for. The code is just an example, I want to be able to use dev tools to find which class/div is causing the problem without looking at the code..